# Definition of Grothendieck ring of varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, schemes

Consider the Grothendieck ring $K_0(\mathcal{V}_k)$ of $$-varieties, with $k$ a field. Then for any $$-variety $$, and closed subset $$ of $$, we have the relation
\begin{equation}
[]=[ \setminus ]+[],
\end{equation}
where $[]$ means the isomorphism class of $$.

This might be a question about terminology in the end, but my question is: when defining $K_0(\mathcal{V}_k)$, one starts from the free abelian group $F_k$ with generators the isomorphism classes of $k$-varieties. Why is $F_k$ closed under all relations of the above type ?

Comment: I don't understand what it means for a group to be closed under a relation.

Comment: @LazzaroCampeotti: I mean: how does one know that classes $[X \setminus C]$ and $[C]$ always define elements of $F_k$? For instance, put $X \setminus C =: Y$, and now consider a relation $[Y] = [Y \setminus L] + [L]$ for some closed subset $L$ of $Y$, etc. Why are $[L]$ and $[Y \setminus L]$ again elements of $F_k$?

Comment: Is your question why $X\setminus C$ and $C$ are varieties if $X$ is a variety and $C$ is a closed subset of $X$?

Comment: @EricWofsey: it is, in fact. Why are they again $k$-varieties ?

Comment: Well, what definition of $k$-variety are you using, and what part of the definition do you not know how to verify?